# Is it possible to create a deadlock in C# if nothing but the lock keyword is used around primitive data access?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I've written a lot of multi-threaded C# code, and I've never had a deadlock in any code I've released.

I use the following rules of thumb:

1. I tend to use nothing but the `lock` keyword (I also use other techniques such as reader/writer locks, but sparingly, and only if required for speed).
2. I use `Interlocked.Increment` if I am dealing with a `long`.
3. I tend to use the smallest granular unit of locking: I only tend to lock around primitive data structures such as `long`, `dictionary` or `list`.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to generate a deadlock *if these rules are thumb are consistently followed*, and if so, what the code would look like?

**Update**

I also use these rules of thumb:

4. Avoid adding a lock around anything that could pause indefinitely, especially I/O operations. If you absolutely have to do so, ensure that absolutely everything within the lock will time out after a set `TimeSpan`.
5. The objects I use for locking are always dedicated objects, e.g. `object _lockDict = new object();` then `lock(_lockDict) { // Access dictionary here }`.

**Update**

Great answer from Jon Skeet. It also confirms why I never get deadlocks as I tend to instinctively avoid nested locks, and even if I do use them, I've always instinctively kept the entry order consistent.

And in response to my comment on tending to use nothing but the `lock` keyword, i.e. using `Dictionary` + `lock` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`, Jon Skeet made this comment:

> @Contango: That's exactly the approach I'd take too.
>   I'd go for simple code with locking over "clever" lock-free code every time, until there's evidence that it's causing an issue.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's easy to deadlock, without actually accessing *any* data:

```
private readonly object lock1 = new object();
private readonly object lock2 = new object();

public void Method1()
{
    lock(lock1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lock(lock2)
        {
        }
    }
}

public void Method2()
{
    lock(lock2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lock(lock1)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Call both `Method1` and `Method2` at roughly the same time, and boom - deadlock. Each thread will be waiting for the "inner" lock, which the other thread has acquired as its "outer" lock.

If you make sure you always acquire locks in the same order (e.g. "never acquire `lock2` unless you already own `lock1`) and release the locks in the reverse order (which is implicit if you're acquiring/releasing with `lock`) then you won't get that sort of deadlock.

You *can* still get a deadlock with async code, with just a single thread involved - but that involves `Task` as well:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    BarAsync().Wait(); // Don't do this!
}

public async Task BarAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

If you run that code from a WinForms thread, you'll deadlock in a single thread - `FooAsync` will be blocking on the task returned by `BarAsync`, and the continuation for `BarAsync` won't be able to run because it's waiting to get back onto the UI thread. Basically, you shouldn't issue blocking calls from the UI thread...

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I think that goes some way towards explaining it. My rule of thumb is to only lock around data primitives  such as `Dictionary` or `List`, which means I never tend to get nested locks.

Comment: @Contango: `Dictionary` and `List` aren't primitive types in the normal meaning of the word. It's not clear what you mean by "lock around" but if you mean in terms of the objects on which you acquire locks, I'd personally stick to references to objects which are used for nothing *but* locking. Otherwise you don't know what other code might take out a lock on the same object.

Comment: Yes. The objects I use for locking are always dedicated objects, e.g. `object _lockDict = new object();` then `lock(_lockDict) { // Access dictionary here }`.

Comment: @Contango Try avoiding locks for collections, for many of the built in .NET collection there are thread safe versions as well, for example the `ConcurrentDictionary`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (how do you make a link in a comment?)

Comment: @flindeberg I used to do that, until I noticed that most times I started down that path, I would hit a situation where I needed some multi-line access to the dictionary, and I would have to refactor all accesses to that dictionary so they are behind a `lock`. And `ConcurrentDictionary` is not actually 100% thread safe either (there are some caveats in the docs). So I gave up and just used `lock` around a plain old `dictionary`. Unless a `lock` is contended, its blindingly fast. Of course, if I really want fast code, I'll use `ConcurrentDictionary` but it's rare that I need the speed.

Comment: @Contango: That's exactly the approach I'd take too. I'd go for simple code with locking over "clever" lock-free code every time, until there's evidence that it's causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you ever only lock on ***one*** thing it's impossible, if one thread tries to lock on multiple locks, then yes. [The dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) nicely illustrates a simple deadlock caused with simple data.

As the other answers have already shown;

```
void Thread1Method()
{
   lock (lock1)
   {
     // Do smth
     lock (lock2)
     { }
   }
}

void Thread2Method()
{
   lock (lock2)
   {
     // Do smth
     lock (lock2) 
     {  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to what Skeet wrote:

The problem normally isn't with "only" two `lock`s... (clearly there could be even with only two `lock`s, but we want to play in Hard mode :-) )...

Let's say that in your program there are 10 `lock`able resources... Let's call them `a1`...`a10`. You must be sure that you'll always `lock` those in the same order, even for subsets of them... If a method needs `a3`, `a5` and `a7`, and another methods needs `a4`, `a5`, `a7`, you must be sure that both will try `lock`ing them in the "right" order. For simplicity sake in this case the order is clear: `a1`->`a10`.

Normally `lock` objects aren't numbered, and/or they aren't taken in a single method... For example:

```
void MethodA()
{
    lock (Lock1)
    {
        CommonMethod();
    }
}

void MethodB()
{
    lock (Lock3)
    {
        CommonMethod();
    }
}

void CommonMethod()
{
    lock (Lock2)
    {
    }
}

void MethodC()
{
    lock (Lock1)
    {
        lock (Lock2)
        {
            lock (Lock3)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, even with the `Lock*` numbered, it isn't immediately clear that the `lock`s could be taken in the wrong order (`MethodB`+`CommonMethod` take `Lock3`+`Lock2`, while `MethodC` takes `Lock1`+`Lock2`+`Lock3`)... It isn't immediately clear and we are playing with three very big advantages: we are speaking of deadlock, so we are looking for them, the `lock`s are numbered and the whole code is around 30 lines.